# print from php application on a local bluetooth printer

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I have the web-based application in 'PHP' and 'MYSQL' mobile version.  We access application from android device (for example Smartphone). There is a local smart Bluetooth printer pairing with Smartphone.  Distributors, who use that application, must take Bluetooth printer on a way, and print a receipt on that printer. Is there any solution for this? Any help or ideas will be appreciated. 2 days I can’t solve this problem.  I can replace android device with any Microsoft device (for example "NOKIA LUMIA"), if it gets me any advantage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that, the printer attached application, has its own web browser. When I navigate to my site from this browser, I discovered, that it has PRINT menu. 
now I'm printing from this browser. I have made the printable version of web page and all is OK!!!!
well done.
My printer model is "MPT-II" (made in china).